# 19.10: Touchpad not working on Lenovo Thinkbook 14 in Ubuntu but worked in Windows

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

The touchpad on my Lenovo [ThinkBook 14-IML Laptop, model 20RV0000MX](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/in/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkbook-series/thinkbook-14-iml/20rv/20rv0000mx) doesn't work in Ubuntu 19.10 or even Linux Mint. However it works on Windows.

I tried the suggestions solution here and other places. it seems that the touchpad is not recognized at all.

When I had Linux Mint before I replaced it with Ubuntu 19.10, I changed the kernel to old and new ones but didn't help.

Is it a easy way to fix this?

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=062a Product=4101 Version=0110
N: Name="MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:062A:4101.0004/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event8 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=062a Product=4101 Version=0110
N: Name="MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:062A:4101.0005/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=062a Product=4101 Version=0110
N: Name="MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:062A:4101.0005/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1f
B: KEY=3f000301ff 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bfd4444600000000 1 130ff38b17c000 677bfad9415fed 19ed68000004400 10000002
B: REL=1040
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=062a Product=4101 Version=0110
N: Name="MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:062A:4101.0005/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=c000 10000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=062a Product=4101 Version=0110
N: Name="MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:062A:4101.0005/input/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=9
B: ABS=10000000000

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0e8f Product=00a8 Version=0110
N: Name="DaKai 2.4G RX"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/0003:0E8F:00A8.0006/input/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event13 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=c000 10000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0e8f Product=00a8 Version=0110
N: Name="DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1/0003:0E8F:00A8.0007/input/input17
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event16 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1f
B: KEY=300ff 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bfd4444600000000 1 130c730b17c000 267bfad9415fed 9e168000004400 10000002
B: REL=1040
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0e8f Product=00a8 Version=0110
N: Name="DaKai 2.4G RX"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1/0003:0E8F:00A8.0007/input/input18
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event17 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=9
B: ABS=10000000000

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Ideapad extra buttons"
P: Phys=ideapad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input24
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000800100c03 4400000000300000 0 2
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=13d3 Product=5415 Version=1906
N: Name="Integrated Camera: Integrated C"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-6/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input25
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input26
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input27
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event18 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input28
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event19 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input29
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event20 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input30
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event21 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input31
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input31
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event22 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input32
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event23 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input33
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event24 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

Output of xinput

```
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse                       id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control            id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control   id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DaKai 2.4G RX                             id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DaKai 2.4G RX System Control              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control            id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Most likely the touchpad is not supported by Linux yet. You can try the latest mainline kernels.

Comment: There are multiple different Lenovo Thinkbook 14 machines https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkbook-series/Lenovo-ThinkBook-14-IML/p/XXTBXTM8000 so please turn it over, and on the label with the serial number, please find the parts model number, something like  20SL001AUS, 20SL0013AUS, 20RV007JUS, or 20SL0017US . Then, please click [edit] and add that number to your original question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Why would you need a serial number?

Comment: @Pilot6 I added S/N to the post

Comment: Please add output of `xinput` command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output of xinput

Comment: The touchpad is not detected. It hasn't been added to Linux kernels yet. You can try to install the latest mainline kernel to see if it is supported there.

Comment: Op cit. "please find the parts model number," I did not ask for the serial number, but for the parts model number ON the serial number sticker.

Comment: @K7AAY I have this to number  MO:LRNXB010600B       ,  MTM: 20RV0000MX Which one you want?

Comment: Op cit. "... please find the parts model number, something like 20SL001AUS, 20SL0013AUS, 20RV007JUS, or 20SL0017US..." Your model parts number is 20RV0000MX  which I added to the question.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have synaptics installed I suggest you do that by opening a terminal.

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Then just look up synaptic and you should see the one for your touchpad.
It's called something like  Synaptics TouchPad driver.

Synaptic package manager:

[image: Synaptic package manager]

Comment: This is a wrong answer. xorg touchpad drivers are installed by default. `libinput` is used in modern Ubuntu releases. The problem  is with kernel drivers.

Comment: then just reinstall the kernal to an older version or just installa diffrent ubuntu since its likelya fsh install that would be the easy fix i would think

Comment: and not if you dont choose to install third party software during the install there not fyi like i said done it before many times seems silly but it happens not saying that is the issue hre but yeah anyways